# Bicep does not resolve 'foo${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}' when deploying from VSCode

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm trying to deploy a Bicep template directly from VSCode with the Bicep extension, but it consistently fails. It works fine when I deploy from PowerShell using the `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet, though. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Bicep template deploys a new storage account and contains the following parameter for the storage account's name:

```
param storageName string = 'mystorage${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
```

### Error when deploying from VSCode

When I deploy from VSCode, it does not resolve `storageName` automatically and prompts me to confirm it:

[image: VScodePrompt]

I believe this prompt is unexpected. `storageName` should be resolved automatically. I press Enter to confirm. This parameter should be resolved automatically alter after all.

And it fails when I attempt to deploy this Bicep template from VSCode. Here is the error status message:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "AccountNameInvalid",
        "message": "[format('mystorage{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))] is not a valid storage account name. Storage account name must be between 3 and 24 characters in length and use numbers and lower-case letters only."
    }
}
```

As far as I see, for some reason, the `storageName` parameter was not resolved into an actual string (see the last line of the output). So it's expected that ARM does not let my deploy this template.

```
Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName VSCodeBicepTest-RG -Name MyTestDeployment-FAILS   

DeploymentName          : MyTestDeployment-FAILS
ResourceGroupName       : VSCodeBicepTest-RG
ProvisioningState       : Failed
Timestamp               : 19/01/2023 19:56:37
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            : 
Parameters              : 
                          Name             Type                       Value     
                          ===============  =========================  ==========
                          location         String                     "northeurope"
                          storageName      String                     "[format('mystorage{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
```

### Works fine from PowerShell

Everything seems to be fine when I deploy the template from PowerShell. The deployment has succeeded:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name MyTestDeployment-SUCCEEDS -ResourceGroupName VSCodeBicepTest-RG -TemplateFile ./sample-template.bicep

DeploymentName          : MyTestDeployment-SUCCEEDS
ResourceGroupName       : VSCodeBicepTest-RG
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 19/01/2023 19:56:16
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            : 
Parameters              : 
                          Name             Type                       Value     
                          ===============  =========================  ==========
                          location         String                     "northeurope"
                          storageName      String                     "mystoragedcgcd6nvj5tje"
```

As you may see, the `storageName` parameter was correctly resolved into the string `mystoragedcgcd6nvj5tje`. That's expected.

Right now, I don't know why this is happening, but it looks like a bug in the Bicep extension for VSCode.

VSCode 1.74.3 (Universal) on MacOS,
Bicep extension v0.13.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a [known bug](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/8154). As a workaround, you may wrap your interpolated parameters with `string()`.

E.g., change this:

```
param storageName string = 'mystorage${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
```

To this:

```
param storageName string = string('mystorage${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that the maximum length of characters does not exceed 24 and the min 3.?

You can add the decorators `@minLength(3)` and `@maxLength(24)`, just above the param for the name.